# Как удалить SLUG из кастомного типа поста в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Есть код который выводит тип поста, я установил в слаге '/'
Это сработало, но из страниц работает только:
1 - Главная страница
2 - Страницы этого типа поста 'post-type-0'

остальные страницы не отображает, покаживает только хедер и футер.

```
// Регистрируем тип произвольных записей
    add_action( 'init', 'register_post_types' );
    function register_post_types(){
        register_post_type('post-type-0', array(
            'label'  => null,
            'labels' => array(
                'name'             => 'Города', // основное название для типа записи
                'singular_name'   => 'Город', // название для одной записи этого типа
                'add_new'           => 'Добавить Город', // для добавления новой записи
                'add_new_item'     => 'Добавление Города', // заголовка у вновь создаваемой записи в админ-панели.
                'edit_item'       => 'Редактирование Города', // для редактирования типа записи
                'new_item'         => 'Новый Города', // текст новой записи
                'view_item'       => 'Смотреть Город', // для просмотра записи этого типа.
                'search_items'     => 'Искать Город', // для поиска по этим типам записи
                'not_found'       => 'Город не найден', // если в результате поиска ничего не было найдено
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'Город не найден в корзине', // если не было найдено в корзине
                'parent_item_colon'  => '', // для родителей (у древовидных типов)
                'menu_name'       => 'Города', // название меню
            ),
            'description'        => '',
            'public'              => true,
            // 'publicly_queryable'  => null, // зависит от public
            // 'exclude_from_search' => null, // зависит от public
            // 'show_ui'             => null, // зависит от public
            // 'show_in_nav_menus'   => null, // зависит от public
            'show_in_menu'      => true, // показывать ли в меню адмнки
            'show_in_admin_bar'   => true, // зависит от show_in_menu
            'show_in_rest'      => true, // добавить в REST API. C WP 4.7
            'rest_base'        => null, // $post_type. C WP 4.7
            'menu_position'    => null,
            'menu_icon'        => null,
            //'capability_type'   => 'post',
            //'capabilities'      => 'post', // массив дополнительных прав для этого типа записи
            //'map_meta_cap'      => null, // Ставим true чтобы включить дефолтный обработчик специальных прав
            // 'hierarchical' => true,
            'supports' => ['title','editor','thumbnail','excerpt','custom-fields','page-attributes','post-formats'], // 'title','editor','author','thumbnail','excerpt','trackbacks','custom-fields','comments','revisions','page-attributes','post-formats'
            'taxonomies' => array('category', 'post_tag'),
            'has_archive'        => false,
            'rewrite'            => true,
            // 'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'goroda'),
            'rewrite' => [
                'slug' => '/',
                'with_front' => true
            ],
            'query_var'        => true,
            'menu_icon'          => 'dashicons-category', // иконка в меню
        ) );
    }
```

Так-же пытался делать что-то типо такого КОД НИЖЕ
Но это тоже не сработало, все страницы отображались кроме тех которые относятся к этому типу постов, так что 404.

```
function sh_remove_cpt_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

    if ( in_array( $post->post_type, array( 'post-type-0' ))
        || 'publish' == $post->post_status )
        $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $post_link );
        return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'sh_remove_cpt_slug', 10, 3 );
function sh_parse_request( $query ) {
    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( 2 != count( $query->query )
        || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) )
        return;
    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post-type-0' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'sh_parse_request' );
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте также скорректировать main_query

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpp_change_request' );

function wpp_change_request( $query ) {
 
    if ( is_admin() || !$query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query[ 'page' ] ) ) {
      return;
    }
    if ( ! empty( $query->query[ 'name' ] ) ) {
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'post-type-0', 'page' ) );
    }
 
}
```

Также удалить slug из ссылки можно фильтром

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'wpp_remove_slug', 10, 3 );

function wpp_remove_slug( $post_link, $post, $name ) {
 
    if ('post-type-0' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
      return $post_link;
    }
    $post_link = str_replace( '/goroda/', '/', $post_link );
 
    return $post_link;
 
}
```

Comment: Удалил с помощью фильтра, заработали все страницы, кроме страниц post-type-0, видно только Хедер и Футер, а контента нет, но слаг удалился )

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко  'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'goroda') - это вернули?

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко посмотрите в отладке, что в main_query

Comment: вот это  'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'goroda')  не возвращал, по поводу main_query я не совсем понимаю как его вардампить

Comment: У меня получаеться ошибка 404тая по страницам этого типа поста

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко верните 'rewrite' => array( 'slug'=>'goroda'),

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко для просмотров запросов удобно пользоваться плагином query-monitor

Comment: Вернул вот скриншот https://prnt.sc/v4c3oa но все-же посты 404

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко добавьте в функцию регистрации поста вызов 
        flush_rewrite_rules();

Comment: Добавил, обновил ссылки, но все так-же 404 в этом типе поста https://prnt.sc/v4d744

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко  а что в главном запросе получается?

Comment: Ну если я перехожу по ссылке которая вывелась получается domen/chernivtsi/ тогда получаем 404 если я руками вписываю domen/goroda/chernivtsi/ тогда работает

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко это ничего не говорит. нужно смотреть main_query. используйте плагин query-monitor

Comment: Не совсем понимаю как пользоваться этим плагином, но вот что он вернул https://prnt.sc/v4fpu4

Comment: @СергейГончарь-Лысенко смотреть запросы - искать где именно 404 сбрасывается

Comment: Я когда подключаю этот плагин у меня выдает ошибку, jQuery не подключено, хотя оно подключено)